# Load and display image from a url

Tags: c#, image, url, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to load an image from url to GameObject.

I found the next tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8UK2EsKBzv8

The download succeeded, but I can't see the image.

What am I doing wrong?

```
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    StartCoroutine(loadSpriteImageFromUrl("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/408px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png"));
}

IEnumerator loadSpriteImageFromUrl(string URL)
{
    // Check internet connection
    if (Application.internetReachability == NetworkReachability.NotReachable)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    var www = new WWW(URL);
    Debug.Log("Download image on progress");
    yield return www;

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.text))
    {
        Debug.Log("Download failed");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Download succes");
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
        www.LoadImageIntoTexture(texture);                      
        Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(texture,
            new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height),      
            Vector2.one / 2);                                     

        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = sprite;    // Change current sprite
    }
}
```

[image: Before Running]
[image: After Running]

**EDIT**

After moving as suggested from ScriptRenderer to UI Image, the code looks like this:

```
IEnumerator loadSpriteImageFromUrl(string URL, GameObject cell)
{
    // Check internet connection
    if(Application.internetReachability == NetworkReachability.NotReachable)
    {
        yield return null;
    }

    var www = new WWW(URL);
    Debug.Log("Download image on progress");
    yield return www;

    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.text))
    {
        Debug.Log("Download failed");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Download succes");
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
        www.LoadImageIntoTexture(texture);                      
        Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(texture, 
            new Rect(0,0, texture.width, texture.height),      
            Vector2.one/2);                                    

        cell.AddComponent<Image>();
        cell.GetComponent<Image>().sprite = sprite;    
    }
}
```

But I'm getting next result to the screen (and not the image in the url):

[image]

Comment: Where is the above script attached in your `hierarchy` ?

Comment: Assets --> Scripts --> LoadImage . And it's attached to an empty game object. Why?

Comment: Your empty `GameObject` needs to have a `SpriteRenderer` component, otherwise your script will never work

Comment: @Hristo I have SpriteRenderer already.

Comment: @Programmer I have SpriteRenderer already. 
I want to display a grid of images from the net.

Comment: Does the sprite change when you run the program? (Where it says `None (Sprite)`)

Comment: @David I have to agree with @Programmer here since its best to use a `RawImage`. Also you have an empty `GameObject` so you wouldn't be able to see the sprite. Try making a `Quad` or a `Plane` and then add the image.

Comment: @Programmer Thanks a lot for your help here! I still encounter a problem so I edit my question again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your code is fine. The downloaded Image is not showing because you are in the Scene-View and the camera is away from it.

[image]

Select the GameObject the script is attached to then press **F**. It should zoom into it and you will see the downloaded image. See [here](https://i.imgur.com/7W7xGFt.gif) for how to reset your Unity layout to get the Game-View back.

[image]

---

---

If you still can't see the image then the `SpriteRenderer` is not in front of the camera. From the screenshot, its position is `0`,`0`,`0` so make sure that the camera's position is `0`,`0`,`-10`.

**The right Way to Display Image:**

To simply display image in Unity, use the `Image` or `RawImage` component. `RawImage` is recommended since it doesn't generate garbage when changing the Texture. You should already know how to di this from th

If you need to attach Rigidbody or 2D Colliders to that Image then use `SpriteRenderer` or `MeshRenderer` for 3D Objects to display the `image`.

*These are the four ways to display an image in Unity. **#2** is recommended if no physics or collision is needed at-all:*

**1**.With the `Image` Component:

```
public Image imageToDisplay;
string url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/408px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png";

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(loadSpriteImageFromUrl(url));
}

IEnumerator loadSpriteImageFromUrl(string URL)
{

    WWW www = new WWW(URL);
    while (!www.isDone)
    {
        Debug.Log("Download image on progress" + www.progress);
        yield return null;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
        Debug.Log("Download failed");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Download succes");
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
        www.LoadImageIntoTexture(texture);

        Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(texture,
            new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), Vector2.zero);

        imageToDisplay.sprite = sprite;
    }
}
```

There have been problems with `LoadImageIntoTexture` in the past. For this reason, my other examples won't use `LoadImageIntoTexture`. If you see a question mark as the Image then use `www.bytes` with the `Texture2D.LoadImage` function.

Simply replace:

```
Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
www.LoadImageIntoTexture(texture);
```

with

```
Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
texture.LoadImage(www.bytes);
texture.Apply();
```

---

**2**.With  the `RawImage` Component(**Recommended**):

```
public RawImage imageToDisplay;
string url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/408px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png";

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(loadSpriteImageFromUrl(url));
}

IEnumerator loadSpriteImageFromUrl(string URL)
{

    WWW www = new WWW(URL);
    while (!www.isDone)
    {
        Debug.Log("Download image on progress" + www.progress);
        yield return null;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
        Debug.Log("Download failed");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Download succes");
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
        texture.LoadImage(www.bytes);
        texture.Apply();


        imageToDisplay.texture = texture;
    }
}
```

**3**.With the `SpriteRenderer` Component:

Mostly used for 2D Objects and 2D physics simulation with *Rigidbody2D* and *2D Colliders*. If not then use the UI(**#1** or **#2**) above.

```
public SpriteRenderer imageToDisplay;
string url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/408px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png";

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(loadSpriteImageFromUrl(url));
}

IEnumerator loadSpriteImageFromUrl(string URL)
{

    WWW www = new WWW(URL);
    while (!www.isDone)
    {
        Debug.Log("Download image on progress" + www.progress);
        yield return null;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
        Debug.Log("Download failed");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Download succes");
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
        www.LoadImageIntoTexture(texture);

        Sprite sprite = Sprite.Create(texture,
            new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), Vector2.zero);


        imageToDisplay.sprite = sprite;
    }
}
```

**4**.With the `MeshRenderer` Component:

Mostly used for 3D Objects and 3D physics simulation with *Rigidbody* and *2D Colliders*. If not then use the UI(**#1** or **#2**) above. Just a use a Plane, Quad or a Cube with a `MeshRenderer`.

```
public MeshRenderer imageToDisplay;
string url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/408px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png";

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(loadSpriteImageFromUrl(url));
}

IEnumerator loadSpriteImageFromUrl(string URL)
{

    WWW www = new WWW(URL);
    while (!www.isDone)
    {
        Debug.Log("Download image on progress" + www.progress);
        yield return null;
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))
    {
        Debug.Log("Download failed");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Download succes");
        Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(1, 1);
        www.LoadImageIntoTexture(texture);

        imageToDisplay.material.mainTexture = texture;
    }
}
```

---

**New Unity version:**

The `WWW` API seems to be deprecated now. `UnityWebRequest` should now be used.

```
public Image imageToUpdate;

void Start()
{
    StartCoroutine(downloadImage());
}

IEnumerator downloadImage()
{
    string url = "http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/hq-images-wallpapers/hq-images-wallpapers-12.jpg";

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url);

    DownloadHandler handle = www.downloadHandler;

    //Send Request and wait
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isHttpError || www.isNetworkError)
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Error while Receiving: " + www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Success");

        //Load Image
        Texture2D texture2d = new Texture2D(8, 8);
        Sprite sprite = null;
        if (texture2d.LoadImage(handle.data))
        {
            sprite = Sprite.Create(texture2d, new Rect(0, 0, texture2d.width, texture2d.height), Vector2.zero);
        }
        if (sprite != null)
        {
            imageToUpdate.sprite = sprite;
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use the `UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture` and `DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent` function to download, process and get the image faster.

```
IEnumerator downloadImage()
{
    string url = "http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/hq-images-wallpapers/hq-images-wallpapers-12.jpg";

    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(url);

    DownloadHandler handle = www.downloadHandler;

    //Send Request and wait
    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isHttpError || www.isNetworkError)
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Error while Receiving: " + www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Success");

        //Load Image
        Texture2D texture2d = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(www);

        Sprite sprite = null;
        sprite = Sprite.Create(texture2d, new Rect(0, 0, texture2d.width, texture2d.height), Vector2.zero);

        if (sprite != null)
        {
            imageToUpdate.sprite = sprite;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for the detailed answer. I tried #1 and #2 and unfortunately I'm still getting a white square with a red `?` mark

Comment: What's your Unity version? Can you zip and send me a simple project that does not work? I will take a look at it. By the way, is your original SpriteRenderer problem solved? I just want to know....

Comment: 5.6.0f3. Can I send it over here? In #2 solution I don't need SpriteRenderer, I just using a RawImage object without it.

Comment: I mean #3. That was the original  way you were doing it before I suggested solution #1 or #2. The first paragraph of my answer mentioned why your original code wasn't working. I just want to know if you fixed that original problem? You can upload the project somewhere and provide the link here. I will take a look at it.

Comment: I tried also #3, but I have the same issue as the original question.

Comment: Here is a link to the project with #2 solution: https://github.com/davidbeloo/TestImageLoadUnity Thanks bro!

Comment: Will take a look now. Was out from my computer

Comment: Dude that code is working properly. I can't tell if you are trolling me or not. You wouldn't have this problem if you copied the code properly.  You used http://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu4SA.png as the url and http://i.stack.imgur.com/Cu4SA.png has a picture with the question mark.....It's getting that exact picture. That's the problem

Comment: I don't even know how you switched from your original url https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/408px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png to that. Test with the original url...

Comment: Finally, there is something wrong with your Canvas that is causing the RawImage not showing in the GameView. *Delete the Canvas and the RawImage component*. Create new Canvas by going to *GameObject-->UI-->Canvas*. Now, select the new Canvas and add RawImage component under it by going to GameObject-->UI-->RawImage. Everything should be fresh again

Comment: Oh and make sure to drag the new RawImage to the imageToDisplay slot.

Comment: Not trolling you at all. I tested it again at home, and you are right, it's working! I guess that in my office the network has some download restrictions that cause this annoying issue! Sorry for that!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Programmer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3785314/programmer) for the detailed answer! I just wanted to add an async version based on Programmer's snippets in case you don't want to work with coroutines

```
public async Task<Sprite> GetSpriteFromURL(string url)
{
    UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequestTexture.GetTexture(url);
    UnityWebRequestAsyncOperation task = www.SendWebRequest();
    
    while (!task.isDone) await Task.Yield();
    if (www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ProtocolError || www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError)
    {
        throw new System.Exception("Error while Receiving: " + www.error);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Success");
        Texture2D tex = DownloadHandlerTexture.GetContent(www);
        return Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0, 0, tex.width, tex.height), Vector2.zero);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public async Task<Sprite> GetImageForX(string example)
{
    if (example == "A") 
        return await GetSpriteFromURL(URL1);
    else 
        return await GetSpriteFromURL(URL2);
}
```